# how to run php from other location in wamp?

Tags: php, webserver, wamp

I want to change the location where my php code runs on localhost, from WAMP.

My current location is in `C:\wamp`, and I want to change it to `E:\server\`

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change the `httpd.conf` in `c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache-xxx.xx\` and look for the `c:/wamp` path. Change it appropriately. In this case `e:/server/`. Save the file, then restart apache and you should be good to go.

Comment: Here is a video howto: [Changing the Apache Root WWW Directory in WAMP Server](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRNe9EnNJOs)